# python detect if string contains junk

Tags: python, filter

I would like to detect in a variable string using python if it contains anything else beside the following i.e 800m2,

so for example

if string = "820m2 bla bla", then boolean = false, 
but if string = "340m2" then boolean is true

Comment: are you checking if `820m2` is in the string or what exactly?

Comment: It's really not clear what counts as true and false here. What is the pattern you're trying to match? 3 digits, a letter and a digit? 3 digits and the specific string "m2"? What?

Comment: voting to close as it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: I believe he's asking to set the variable to False if the string contains '820m2' and True in any other case.

Comment: @iwin, it is completely unclear from the question, it should not be a guessing game to figure out what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions `r'^\d+m2$'` (`re` module) to match this string pattern:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^\d+m2$')  # assuming that m2 == square meter
>>> bool(pattern.search("340m2"))
True
>>> bool(pattern.search("820m2 bla bla"))
False
```

Regular expression explained:

- `^` means "starts with"
- `\d` means "digits"
- `+` means "one or more" (in this case: "one or more digits")
- `m2` means "m2" literally
- `$` means "ends with"

So, we got the expression: "Match strings that starts with one or more digits and ends with 'm2'".

Comment: hits the spot thnks,

Comment: what if i would like to search for 340$ instead of m2 pls

Comment: @Ossama `pattern = re.compile(r'^\d+\$$')`

Comment: You don't need to specify `^` when you use [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) or [`re.RegexObject.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match), because it matches at the beginning of the string unlike `search`.

Comment: Yes, you are right @falsetru. I always forget what method does not need the `^`. Fixed the answer to use `.search()` instead of `.match()` because I prefer more "explicit" regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> bool(re.search('^\d+m\d+$', "820m2 bla bla"))
False
>>> bool(re.search('^\d+m\d+$', "340m2"))
True
```

`\d` matches any digit character. `\d+` matches one or more digits.

`^` matches at the beginnig of the string, `$` matches at the end of the string.